# Instagram API Subscription, how to get post?

Tags: php, api, post, instagram

I'm working to understand how to get the results of a Instagram Subscription that looks for a specific tag. Ultimately, what I would like to do is as images are posted with the tag I'm looking for add the link to the photo as well as the username to a database.

I was able to create my subscription no problem but now I'm not sure how to get the POST information from the subscription.

Working with two files...subscribe.php and callback.php

**subscribe.php**

```
<?php

//ALL YOUR IMPORTANT API INFO
$client_id = 'XXX';
$client_secret = 'XXX';
$object = 'tag';
$object_id = 'taglookingfor';
$aspect = 'media';
$verify_token='';
$callback_url = '(full URL here)/callback.php';


//SETTING UP THE CURL SETTINGS...
$attachment =  array(
'client_id' => $client_id,
'client_secret' => $client_secret,
'object' => $object,
'object_id' => $object_id,
'aspect' => $aspect,
'verify_token' => $verify_token,
'callback_url'=>$callback_url
);

//URL TO THE INSTAGRAM API FUNCTION
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/";

$ch = curl_init();

//EXECUTE THE CURL...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

//PRINT THE RESULTS OF THE SUBSCRIPTION, IF ALL GOES WELL YOU'LL SEE A 200
print_r($result);


?>
```

**callback.php**

```
 <?php

if (isset ($_GET['hub_challenge'])){
    echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
}

//This is an update
else {

    $myString = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $answer = json_decode($myString);
    echo $answer;
}

?>
```

In my callback.php I'm attempting to echo out the results of the json_decode...but that also begs the question how will I catch that echo? Sorry, this might be really silly but how do I catch the moment when the callback.php script is being fired by a new image with the specific tag I'm looking for. As I mentioned what I hope to do is take the info in the $answer and insert some of the info into a database.

I'm new at this so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks a million!!

Comment: did you get your data in the end? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 6):

I feel your pain. Their API isn't the easiest to work with and their documentation leaves  lot to be desired. That said, this is what happens:

1. You send a request to the subscription API endpoint
2. Instagram sends a response to your callback.php file
3. The response contains a hub_challenge parameter that you need to echo to confirm your subscription
4. If it's successful you will get a post to your callback.php with the subscriptionid of your new subscription
5. Everytime you get a post to your callback.php you need to fire a request to Instagram for their latest media that matches your tag.

Answer (score 0):

i think your callback url is not able to receive any post data, you may try to post something to your callback url

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44292284/5321614) answer of mine will be helpful to people having similar problem.