# Not receiving Instagram real time notifications

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have created a [real time tag subscription](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) using the following curl call

```
curl -F 'client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
     -F 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
     -F 'object=tag' \
     -F 'aspect=media'  \
     -F 'object_id=socialjohn' \
     -F 'callback_url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/realtime/instagram' 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

I get a successful 200OK response from Instagram

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": {
        "object": "tag",
        "object_id": "socialjohn",
        "aspect": "media",
        "callback_url": "http:\/\/xxxxxxxx\/realtime\/instagram",
        "type": "subscription",
        "id": "xxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

When I post a picture on Instagram with the hashtag #socialjohn, I don't see the notification for the tag coming though.

I have the same issue when I created a user subscription. I do not receive any real time notification for the user. I did a GET subscriptions after the posting the picture to ensure that my subscriptions are not deleted by Instagram. The GET call was successful with a 200 OK and the body containing all the subscriptions I am subscribed to.

In order to check if something suspicious is happening on my end, I created a subscription for a high volume tag like #galaxy or #smile and I can see that I receive the real time notifications.

Has anyone experienced the same issue? Is there something I am missing here or that I should be doing in order to receive the notifications

**Resolution:**
After talking to Instagram support, we decided to use a polling model to fetch Instagram posts. The API appears to be unreliable and doesn't seem to scale well.

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634625/instagram-subscription-api-asking-for-access-token/44292284#44292284) will be helpful for similar problem.