# Not getting intended data from instagram subscription api call

Tags: instagram

I followed the subscription api(https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/) and created a subscription request like this:

```
curl -F 'client_id=clientId' \
     -F 'client_secret=clientSecret' \
     -F 'object=user' \
     -F 'aspect=media' \
     -F 'verify_token=my-verify-token' \
     -F 'callback_url=https://xx.xx.com/igwh' \
     https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

and got response as bellow:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    }, 
    "data": {
            "object": "user", 
            "object_id": null, 
            "aspect": "media", 
            "subscription_id": 0, 
            "callback_url": "https://xx.xx.com/igwh", 
            "type": "subscription", 
            "id": 0
    }
}
```

My app is in live mode, so is that normal to get the "object_id": null, "subscription_id": 0 and  "id": 0 onto the response?
After that when my another authenticated instagram account shared a media then I got notification to my callback url but seems to me lack of information:

```
[
    {
        "changed_aspect": "media",
        "object": "user",
        "object_id": "111111",
        "time": 1484290271,
        "subscription_id": 0,
        "data": {
            "media_id": "1111-11"
        }
    }
]
```

I said lack of information because a media have "id", "images", "caption", "link" etc which I was expecting as a response.
Because otherwise I have to call normal api(Media enpoints) call again to get those things. Is there anything I missed to get the subscription or have different way to get?

https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/

this endpoint says "When we have new data, we'll POST this data to your callback URL. We'll explain more about what this URL needs to do later on this page."
Although I can't get the subscription api response if I comment on the media(which I had got the notification in my callback url) or liked on the media/comment.
Is that those things not supported by instagram? Does anyone have this issue or any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44292284/5321614) answer of mine will be helpful to people having same problem.