# using wp_set_auth_cookie with out any hook

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, instagram-api, wordpress-login

Wordpress version 4.7.5

I am signing up new users from Instagram, I am successfully able signup the new user. after signup I am trying to logged in the user.

> I can use hook, but would like better solution than the dirty one, I
>   have posted as that will be totally unuseful .

```
if( $user_created ) {
    $new_user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_created ); 
    //$loggedin = programmatic_login( $new_user->user_login );
    //ob_start();
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user( $user_created, $new_user->user_login );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_created, true );
        do_action( 'wp_login', $new_user->user_login );
        // wp_safe_redirect(site_url() . '/profile/');
        // exit;
        // $redirect_to=user_admin_url();
        // wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
        // exit();
    }
    //ob_end_clean();
} ?>
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){ window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url() . '/profile/'; ?>";});</script> <?php
```

also tried with a custom [programmatic_login](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/156431) function from another post.

if I am trying to `var_dump`  `wp_get_current_user()` and `$_COOKIE` below this, I am getting user object for `wp_get_current_user()` and `array(1) { ["wordpress_test_cookie"]=> string(15) "WP Cookie check" }` for `$_COOKIE` .

**Important Edit**

The code is inside a function, which is hooked to a hook, that is called in side a page that is after header is getting displayed, so we could not use init here. any other way of doing it and also because of this `wp_safe_redirect()` or `header('Location: ')` also not working .

**Important Update with what I have just tried**

**A dirty work around**

when I created the user from Instagram login, After successful creation I redirected the user to a page with get parameter something like `?user_id=$inserted_id` and on wp hook, I tried to  get the `GET['user_id']` and logged it and it worked, trying to find a proper solution.

```
if ( $wpdb->insert_id ){  //that is registration with instagram
   ?>
    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){ window.location.href = "<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') . '/profile/?id=' . $wpdb->insert_id; ?>";});</script>
   <?php
}
```

and then

```
add_action( 'wp', 'login_current_user' );
function login_current_user(){
    if ( is_page() && get_the_id() == 863 ){
        if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ){
            if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $user_id = $_GET['id'];
                $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id ); 
                wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
                wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true );
                do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
                if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
                    $redirect_to=site_url() . '/profile';
                    wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Proble with dirty trick. If the `id` we are passing as get parameter
>   exists in wp_users table then with no verification that will be logged
>   in .

**Update**

*I created a user_meta before redirecting to profile page and after verification login the user and removed the usermeta, just like an OTP . Trying to make it better if possible.*

Below the code:-

```
if ( $wpdb->insert_id ){  //that is registration with instagram
    $temporary_token = sha1(rand());
    update_user_meta( $wpdb->insert_id, 'temporary_token', $temporary_token);
   ?>
    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){ window.location.href = "<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') . '/profile/?id=' . $wpdb->insert_id . '&token=' . $temporary_token; ?>";});</script>
   <?php
}
```

and then

```
add_action( 'wp', 'login_current_user' );
    function login_current_user(){
        if ( is_page() && get_the_id() == 863 ){
            if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ){
                if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    $user_id = $_GET['id'];
                    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
                    if ( $_GET['token'] == get_user_meta( $user_id, 'temporary_token', true ) ){
                        delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'temporary_token', $_GET['token'] ); 
                        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                        wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
                        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true );
                        do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
                        if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
                            $redirect_to=site_url() . '/profile';
                            wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
                            exit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If headers are being sent before `wp_set_auth_cookie()` then the cookie may not end up being set. If you can hook the init action `add_action( 'init', 'my_action' );` and make the calls there instead it might fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If headers have been sent before `wp_clear_auth_cookie()` or `wp_set_auth_cookie()` are called then neither will work as both rely on PHP's `setcookie` function. The `after_setup_theme` action will occur before headers have been sent so hooking that and setting the cookies there should fix the issue.

```
function myPlugin_createUser(){
  // Probably need to put code that creates user here too otherwise $user_created will never return true
  if( $user_created ) {
      $new_user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_created ); 
      if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
          wp_clear_auth_cookie();
          wp_set_current_user( $user_created, $new_user->user_login );
          wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_created, true );
          do_action( 'wp_login', $new_user->user_login );
      }
  } 
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'myPlugin_createUser' );
```

**Update:**

If you're outputting view elements before triggering your `createUser` function it won't work so we need to make sure they run completely independent of each other. Below I've put together a simple example of how to achieve this - to the view we output a link which passes a GET parameter, this parameter is picked up by the plugin and runs the action before anything is rendered allowing us to set the cookie.

**my-plugin.php**

```
// Note: you'll need to include a completed version of myPlugin_createUser() function as above for these examples to work
add_shortcode( 'my-plugin', function() {  
   // I've used a GET request for simplicity- a form + POST request may be more practical for your purposes and will prevent caching issues.
   echo "<a href='?my_plugin_login_user=1'>Login</a>";
});

// Check for our GET parameter 
if( isset( $_GET['my_plugin_login_user'] ) ) {
  // Nothing should be rendered yet as plugin template hasn't even started loading yet so cookies should set fine
  add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'myPlugin_createUser' ); 
}
```

**page-my-template.php**

```
<div> ...
    <?php 
        do_shortcode( 'my-plugin' ); 
    ?>
</div>
```

**Update 2:** 
If using Instagrams Authentication API the explicit flow outlined https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/ (most of the examples used below are taken from there) is probably the best approach. Below I'll give a brief rundown of how you could implement it. Much of it is taken from there with notes added.

**Send the user off to https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code**

You could include the WordPress user ID as a parameter on the callback URL or if the user hasn't yet been created and you need to maintain state then you'll need to generate a temporary token that you can use later that's been associated with said data or store that data client side if it's not sensitive which is probably easier and better as it doesn't require a user to be logged in to function.

**The user will then login**

Not much to say about this step - if an error occurs they'll be redirected to `http://your-redirect-uri?error=access_denied&error_reason=user_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request`

**If login is successful the user will be redirected to `http://your-redirect-uri?code=CODE`**

The `CODE` passed back on the redirect URL we can redeem for an access token.

So from here there's a multitude of ways we can handle it but essentially what we need is an endpoint for the redirect that we have sufficient control over to send HTTP headers before any of the HTTP response body is sent.

Methods of approaching this (not an exhaustive list):

- Conditionally hooking on pages Instagram auths are allowed (as in your examples). This has the advantage of not requiring an additional redirect.
- Custom page template
- External script that manually bootstraps WordPress does what we need, then redirects back in

**So now once we've got an endpoint setup we need to redeem the `CODE`for an access token. Adapted this snippet from https://gist.github.com/arturmamedov/7f5a90b85a20e06e344ebb88dc898d25**

```
$uri = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token'; 
$data = [
    'client_id' => '213esdaedasdasd12...YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 
    'client_secret' => 'a8b4aaf06c0da310...YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET', 
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.YOUR_REDIRECT_URL.it',      // The exact redirect URL as used previously
    'code' => $_GET['code']  
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri); // uri
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // POST DATA
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // RETURN RESULT true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // RETURN HEADER false
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0); // NO RETURN BODY false / we need the body to return
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // VERIFY SSL HOST false
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // VERIFY SSL PEER false
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

$result will be an object representation of the JSON response:

```
{
"access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
"user": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "..."
  }
}
```

From here we just create our user/authenticate with WordPress and redirect to the desired page/render the template (no need to redirect if handled via conditional hooks) and restore the page state if needed.

Comment: thank you for your response, It does not seems I can use init hook here. during my search, I found some people have suggested it, but in my case I could not use, also I found even If I will  not want to redirect I can use ob_start() and ob_end(), but that too did not worked.

Comment: You're very welcome :) Sorry is it that you can't use `init`? Or that `init` doesn't work?  If neither output buffering or the `init` action works then likely there's some output occurring or the call to `add_action` is occurring too late so to solve the problem we probably need to know more about how/where this is being called from and possibly a larger code snippet as the other reason the cookie may not be set is if `$user_created` evaluates as `false`.

Comment: thank you for your effort to add more idea into it, $user_created as well as wp_get_current_user() is working fine, as I have described  in question . I am looking into again if I could use a do action here and will update the question .

Comment: the code is inside a function, which is hooked to a hook, that is called in side a page that is after header is getting displayed, so we could not use init here, any other idea ??

Comment: I think you'll probably have to move your code into your `functions.php` or within a plugin then trigger it with a `$_GET`, `$_POST` variable or register a custom URL which you redirect to does the work then back. The actions need to be hooked before any output otherwise they won't work so doing it within a template is no good a lot of the time.  Depending on how and where you're doing this - `after_setup_theme` is the earliest hook available to themes and happens before auth so that may also be of use to you.

Comment: function is inside a custom plugin, hook is in a template . I am also trying to little bit reorganized if possible. I will update it again soon.

Comment: Updated my answer to try and give a better idea of how you can structure it so that the view and creation/login of the user is separate to allow the authentication cookies to be set. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Going through your answer and also I have some updates I will share with you :D

Comment: what I have just tried with init hook is similar to your suggestion and it did not worked, after creation of user, I redirected to desire page and on init hook checked if that page and logged the user in by setting cookie and again redirected to same page without get parameter . do you think I have tried something wrong ?

Comment: trying with wp hook.

Comment: and it is working now :D will try to find a better way for some time now . as it is a dirty trick.

Comment: and your effort was really helpful to get this dirty workaround and also gives hope to create a better solution, so upvoted  .

Comment: I notice a bigger issue in this method, check question, I have mentioned it there .

Comment: Yeah it'd be safer to pass it via POST or even better still to generate a single use or time limited code on creation which is used to login. Using user id to login via a get request would be very insecure as an attacker could login via browser history or just "brute forcing" a valid id. There's probably a better way still to go using the Instagram authentication API, although I'm a little too tired and have a bit of a headache sorry so not really feeling up to going through that at the moment.

Comment: I am already thankful to you for your effort my friend, I am also trying hard to get some way around it, as it will also be useful in future . you do not have any social network or github on your profile, I was thinking to be connected .

Comment: Update, I used postmeta as a temporary token and feel may be a better solution as you hinted yesterday and continuing to find still better possible solution .

Comment: Nice work! I think tokens are definitely a good step in the right direction and much less prone to abuse. I'm feeling a bit better so I've updated my answer with some suggestions on how to best implement this assuming you're using the Instagram Authentication API which I think is the best approach. I've kept the answer very general so you may need to review the documentation and adapt as required.

I've also added my Github account to my profile - although I'm not as active on there as I'd like to be as unfortunately many of my previous projects for employers have been closed source.

Comment: for wordpress better to use wp_remote_post and wp_remote_get . Also I have an [answer regarding use of instagram api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634625/instagram-subscription-api-asking-for-access-token/44292284#44292284) , so I do not think explaining this process has any necessity here .

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware WordPress had those available - I'd always used either `curl` or `file_get_contents` previously. My goal was to more explain how to create and authenticate a user after interacting with the API. I was a little worried it may have been exceeding the scope of the question a little sorry if I went a bit overboard. Is there anything you're still having trouble with? I need to clean up the answer at some point - it's become a bit of a mess and the question has changed significantly since my initial answer

Comment: no need to say sorry, I was worried as people will see your answer and confuse themselves about the actual problem. It is working from tomorrow as We have spoken, but I am trying to something better, it still seems as a workaround, if there will be no other option, I may think to go with this, as workaround are not accepted in my job :(

Comment: lets see if there will be any better approach, but I have awarded the bounty to you, please update your answer with my suggestions.

Comment: No worries, thanks very much mate :). I've been feeling pretty average the past few days sorry but will edit/update the answer as soon as I'm up to it.

Comment: @Brian i rarely make a comment for trivial answer, but yours was not trivial and was of great help. THANKS A TON!